# Change of a function and approximate value

Tags: calculus, functions

Compute approximate value of a function change
  $y=x^3 - x^2$ when $x=2$ and $x=0.01$. Any ideas how to solve it?

Attempt based on feedback in the comments:

$\Delta x = dx$ and $\Delta y= dy$, then $f(x+ \Delta x) = f(x) + f′(x) \cdot \Delta x$. $\Delta x = 2-0,01=1,99$. Then $f(0,01) + f′(0,01) \cdot 1,99 = \ldots$

Where $f'(x) = 3x^2 - 2x$.

Comment: Have you been introduced to the concept of derivatives yet?  If so, what is $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in this situation?  What does it have to do with how the function changes according to $x$?  If not, then what tools *do* you have available?

Comment: Derivative is 3x^2-2x. But what is next step?

Comment: Generally speaking, you solve this problem with differentials and the derivative, as JMoravitz has hinted: $dy=y'(x)\,dx$. What are $dy$ and $dx$ for your problem? That is, how would you interpret them for your problem?

Comment: so, Δx = dx and Δy= dy, then f(x+Δx) = f(x) + f′(x)*Δx. . Δx = 2-0,01=1,99. then f(0,01) +  f ′ (0,01) * 1,99 = ....... Am I right?

Comment: Did you mean to write $\Delta x = 0.01$?

Comment: Excercise says x=2 and x=0.01